# Convert simple android game made in Java to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I cant find answer for this question any where on web, so what better place to post it then here. I have simple android game made on eclipse in Java. Can anybody give me pointers how can i convert that game and also make it available on facebook as a facebook game?

Comment: Facebook games are generally written in Flash. You will need to convert Java into ActionScript.

Comment: @RyanBerger - Are there any tools available to do that? or will i have to write the whole code from scratch?

Comment: Not any that I'm aware of. You'll likely need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the game to FLASH, or HTML to run it as a Facebook Application. I don't think there'll be a straightforward conversion tool for this.